# ¿ Fallo con recyclerView en vez del ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, recyclerview

El siguiente código con `ListView` en vez de `RecyclerView` me dejaba compilar y ejecutar pero si no me aparece un fallo en la línea de:

`recyclerview.setAdapter(new ImagenAdapter(getApplicationContext()));`

y me dice que :

> setAdapter
>   (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)
>   in RecyclerView cannot be applied

Simplemente he cambiado donde ponía `ListView` --> `RecyclerView` cambiando el correspondiente layout pero nada, me sale ese error y no consigo solucionarlo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerview;

ArrayList titulo = new ArrayList();
ArrayList descripcion = new ArrayList();
ArrayList imagen = new ArrayList();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    descargarImagen();
}

private void descargarImagen() {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando Datos...");
    progressDialog.show();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://rudeboys.esy.es/valbit/query.php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        titulo.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("titulo"));
                        descripcion.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion"));
                        imagen.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagen"));
                    }

//////////En esta línea de bajo es EL FALLO/////////////
                    recyclerview.setAdapter(new ImagenAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}

private class ImagenAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    SmartImageView smartImageView;
    TextView tvtitulo, tvdescripcion;

    public ImagenAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
        this.ctx = applicationContext;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagen.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_item,null);

        smartImageView = (SmartImageView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.imagen1);
        tvtitulo = (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvtitulo);
        tvdescripcion = (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);

        String urlfinal ="http://rudeboys.esy.es/valbit/images/"+imagen.get(position).toString();
         Rect rect = new Rect(smartImageView.getLeft(), smartImageView.getTop(), smartImageView.getRight(), smartImageView.getBottom());

         smartImageView.setImageUrl(urlfinal,rect);

        return viewGroup;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en tu `ImagenAdapter`. Está heredando de `BaseAdapter`, y esto funcionaba para los ListView. Cuando se introdujo el RecyclerView cambio a `RecyclerView.Adapter<TestViewHolder>`.

Un ejemplo de un adapter para un RecyclerView sería así adaptado a tu caso:

```
private class ImagenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagenAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context ctx;
ArrayList imagen = new ArrayList();

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    SmartImageView smartImageView;
    TextView tvtitulo, tvdescripcion;

    MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        smartImageView = (SmartImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imagen1);
        tvtitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtitulo);
        tvdescripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
    }
}

public ImagenAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
    this.ctx = applicationContext;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imagen.size();
}

@Override
public ImagenAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_main_item, parent, false);
    return new ImagenAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ImagenAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    String urlfinal ="http://rudeboys.esy.es/valbit/images/"+imagen.get(position).toString();
    Rect rect = new Rect(holder.smartImageView.getLeft(), holder.smartImageView.getTop(), holder.smartImageView.getRight(), holder.smartImageView.getBottom());
    holder.smartImageView.setImageUrl(urlfinal,rect);
}
}
```

Algunos de los cambios fueron:

- Declaras un MyViewHolder para reutilizar las vistas.
- La recuperación de los elementos del view se hacen en el constructor de la clase MyViewHolder.
- En el método `onCreateViewHolder` es donde inflas el view para cada posición.
- El método `onBindViewHolder` ya tiene la vista cargada y su función es para que enlaces la data de tu lista con los elementos del view según la posición.

Esto es un resumen de la transición que hubo de ListView -> RecyclerView.